# how to disable line break in the textbox control

Tags: excel, vba

I was working on VBA within Excel 2013, I created a textbox and assigned values to the textbox.text property.
the values was generated by following code:

```
values = "abcd" & chr(10) "efg" & chr(10)
textbox1.text = values
```

but when I run the userform, I can see there are 2 line break marks at the end of the string abcd and efg, so do you guys know how to disable this link break marks in the textbox control?

Comment: What do you mean by "line break marks"? Isn't a line break what you would expect when you have `Chr(10)` i.e. the line break character in your string?

Comment: If you mean you are seeing the line break character and not an actual line break you need to change the MultiLine property of your text box to True

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Chr(10)`. That is the line break character.